# NetBeans claims Method parameters differ in length, but actually they do not

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

I am using Netbeans 11 on Windows 10 to test code with JUnit 4.

The method to test looks like this:

```
public DataResult getCmsDatenProtokollDetailAsDres(IDatenprotokoll datenprotokoll, 
                                                    List<Datenprotokoll> allChanges) {
    ...
}
```

I am calling the method like that:

```
result = instance.getCmsDatenProtokollDetailAsDRes(datenprotokoll, allChanges);
```

where result is expected return value DataResult, datenprotokoll is from Class Datenprotokoll, which implements IDatenprotokoll interface and allChanges is a List from Datenprotokoll objects.

Everything works fine and tests are running and calling method like expected.
For any reason, Netbeans marks that line as an error, though compiles and runs it. (Screenshot below)

Any way to fix this? That project is a Maven project, I already did "Clean & Build" several times.[image]

Comment: that most likely mean you are not using the version of that class you think you are using. Netbeans doesn't "make mistakes" like this, but the person using it might.

Comment: Which Java version do you use to run NetBeans? (That's not necessarily the same as the Java version for your project) And which NetBeans version?

Comment: Could you plz put the test case code

Comment: How can I see which version the class to test has?
I am using Java 11 in NetBeans as well as in that project. NetBeans 11.2
I won't share the test code, because it doesn't have anything to do with that issue.